# Is there a need to use super.onActivityResult() in onActivityResult()?

Tags: java, android

Which one is better and why?

This one:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    ...
}
```

or this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    // do not call super.onActivityResult()
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The first one is better.

It's more consistent with other event functions in the `Activity` API, it costs you nothing (the code you're calling does nothing at the moment), and it means you don't need to remember to add the call in the future when the behaviour of the base class changes.

**Edit**

As Su-Au Hwang has pointed out, my prediction about the behaviour of the base class changing in the future has come true! `FragmentActivity` **requires** you to call the method on `super`.

Comment: if you are using FragmentActivity from the support Package, you have to call super, see my answer.

Answer (score 27):

You should call super.onActivityResult if you are using FragmentActivity from the support package (also SherlockFragmentActivity). Otherwise it isn't necessary, however i'd just plug it in there for the sake of it. Check the source of FragmentActivity (no onActivityResult is not empty).

[FragmentActivity source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.java)

Comment: link is dead, how about the `AppCompatActivity` in `AndroidX`? It seems like it uses the Androidx `FragmentActivity` as a Base Class, which also has code in it.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have multiple subclasses of `Activity` which depend on it in your application, it doesn't look like calling `super.onActivityResult()` is needed, since the implementation of `onActivityResult()` is empty (I checked API level 15).

Answer (score 3):

You can answer this yourself by looking at the source code for [Activity](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java).

Basically it's implementation of `onActivityResult(...)` looks like this...

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
}
```

...so does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Although it seems the default implementation is empty, it's possible that in future updates that might not always be the case. I would recommend using it

Answer (score 1):

Calling super is mandatory now. It throws "Overriding method should call super.onActivityResult" error. Adding super won't hurt your code.

Answer (score 0):

Well First you need to understand onActivityResult is a callback when there is an action done with intent like choosing, clicking a photo, etc, and super().onActivityResult() returns an exception when the activity of intent gets crashed or something like that happens.
In short super().onActivityResult() is use to handle the error or exception during execution of Intent.

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    if (!mActivityResultRegistry.dispatchResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

### Exception

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}
```